# Receive multiple values in query parameter in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman

I want to receive multiple values in query parameter in spring boot, but I'm getting 404 error while passing the parameter.. anyone please help me?

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/getreport")
    public ResponseEntity<?> parameterValidation(@RequestParam Map<String, String> requestParam) {
        
        int siteId = Integer.parseInt(requestParam.get("siteId"));
        String pageGroup = requestParam.get("pagegroup");
        String deviceType = requestParam.get("devicetype");
        int mode = Integer.parseInt(requestParam.get("mode"));
        String errorCode = requestParam.get("errorcode");
        Long topUrlCount = Long.parseLong(requestParam.get("topurlcount"));
        String orderBy = requestParam.get("orderby");
        String startDate = requestParam.get("startdate");
        String endDate = requestParam.get("enddate");

        if (validation.isSiteIdValid(siteId) && validation.isDeviceValid(deviceType) && validation.isModeValid(mode)
                && validation.isTopUrlCountValid(topUrlCount) && validation.isOrderByValid(orderBy)
                && validation.isStartDateValid(startDate) && validation.isEndDateValid(endDate)) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("VAlIDATION SUCCESS !", HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("OOPS SOMETHING WENT WRONG !, PLEASE CHECK QUERY PARAMETER !", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
```

Comment: 404 means that the request you send cannot be mapped on a controller method.

Answer (score 0):

first: 404 is your controller haven't request url mapping.
  second: you can use class to receive multiple values.

```java
    public class Param{
      private Integer siteId;
      private String pagegroup;
      private String devicetype;
      private Integer mode;
      private String errorcode;
      private Long topurlcount;
      private String orderby;
      @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
      private LocalDateTime startdate;
      @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
      private String enddate;
    
    }
    
    
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/getreport")
    public ResponseEntity<?> parameterValidation(Param requestParam) {

        if (validation.isSiteIdValid(requestParam.getSiteId()) && validation.isDeviceValid(requestParam.getDeviceType()) && validation.isModeValid(requestParam.getMode())
                && validation.isTopUrlCountValid(requestParam.getTopUrlCount()) && validation.isOrderByValid(requestParam.getOrderBy())
                && validation.isStartDateValid(requestParam.getStartDate()) && validation.isEndDateValid(requestParam.getEndDate())) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("VAlIDATION SUCCESS !", HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("OOPS SOMETHING WENT WRONG !, PLEASE CHECK QUERY PARAMETER !", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
```